# Google Map in SSRS Report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I want to create a SSRS report with integrating Google maps . I want to show map location dynamically with help of parameter value's.

Can you please help me.

Comment: Are you planning on running in the browser only?  What is the expected behavior of the maps if the user exports the report to csv, pdf or excel?

Comment: No currently i want to use it as a SSRS report only

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the Static Maps API, available [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

You can use URL parameters to determine what the map should look like, and any locations you wish to display on it.

Comment: I am able to use static map location in my report but i want to fetch location based on the report parameter value. For eg. if i pass value to report parameter as 'India' then a report should show the location of india and so on .

Comment: OK, so you would need to use an expression to populate the ImageURL in the report. The Static Maps API uses a few different parameters for this. You could probably use ?center=India and be fine.

Comment: Correct. Can you guide me to link report parameter with the Google Map API's url ?